# Can we position output anywhere on the page based on user input?

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible in crystal reports to let the user enter page coordinates and position the output at that location?

From here i got to know that for user input we can use prompt -

https://answers.sap.com/questions/8928788/capturing-and-displaying-user-input-in-crystal-rep.html

But is there any way to dynamically set the output position in the report?

Like, can we set the report to begin from any location of the page rather than the top left corner?

The output can be either a single barcode or any single value only.

**EDIT :**

I have a barcode report that looks like this -

[image]

Sometimes, there can be a case when we only have to print one barcode. So, in that case, the report looks like this -

[image]

But we do not want this single barcode to be printed at the top left corner of the page every time.
We want the barcode to be printed at a user specified location. For example, when previewing the report, the user should be prompted for input, for which he should provide some position parameters then then the barcode should be printed like this -

[image: ![enter image description here]

or like this -

[image]

or at any other part of the page.

The reason we are doing this is because there can be data already printed on the pages so we  want to print the barcode accordingly.

Comment: There are several candidate techniques but the use case is not clear enough.
Please provide more concrete details.

Comment: @MilletSoftware Hello, please see the edit. I have provided the example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a limited number of possible desired positions, you can place the output in all those positions and suppress those that don't match the parameter.

Comment: Actually i was confused about those parameters. Are there any parameters in crystal reports that let us dynamically move the data at some other point on the page? Like x axis, y axis and if yes then how do we set them?

Comment: Like i wanted to know which parameters should we check so that we know which barcode to suppress and which not?